# Typescript/Javascript get promise result in callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, callback

I have two third party functions which I cannot change:

One functions expects a callback that possibly could return a new data, not promise.
The other function returns the new data in promise.
How to connect these two functions together?

I have looked at various examples, they always suggests to use Promise.then or async await, but I don't see it applicable inside a callback.

```js
// One 3rd party API
runExternalTransaction(callback: (currentData: any) => unknown) {
// Some 3rd party code.
}

// The other 3rd party API
getNewData(): Promise<any> {
// Some 3rd party code to get data from data storage.
}

// An attempt to put these functions together
runExternalTransaction(currentData => {
    if (!currentData) { // Only return new data if current data not available.
        getNewData().then(newData => ...);
        // How to return new data?
        return ...;
    }
});
```

Comment: To convert a callback function to a promise you need to use the Promise constructor pattern,  -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: @Keith Thanks, I have seen the Promise constructor pattern, but I don't see how to use it for my problem, maybe I am missing something, could you please apply it to my example?

Comment: I don't see any async code in your example,.. aka.  The function you said expects a callback.

Comment: @Keith The async part is the other third party function getNewData() which returns a promise. I need to get the data from the promise and return them from the callback.

Comment: `getNewData().then(newData => /* new data here */)`   btw.  `runExternalTransaction` will need to either use a callback or return a promise if your expecting the caller to get the return value.

Comment: runExternalTransaction((currentData: any) => {
    if (!currentData) {         
        getNewData().then(newData => /* new data here */);
        // how to return the new data?
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to promisify the first one, and then chain the promise you get with the second promise:

```
// Promisify the first 3rd party API
const promiseExternalTransaction = () => new Promise(runExternalTransaction);

promiseExternalTransaction().then(currentData => {
    return currentData && getNewData();
}).then(newData => {
    if (newData) {
       // Do something with new data...
    }
});
```

Note that the promisification looks very simple here, because the callback is the *first* argument that is passed to `runExternalTransaction`, *and* that callback gets the result as *first* argument. If any of these two aspects is different, you need a bit more code to define `promiseExternalTransaction`.

It should be clear that you need to process the asynchronous result in a `then` callback (or following an `await` in an `async` function), and cannot expect the result to be returned to *synchronously* running code, as that would be mean you would get a *future* result *now*.